# Looking for a Russian word

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

Is there a wording or a word in Russian for people that are just "uninformed". In one of the languages I use I do not want to insult them but I want to signal that I do not want anything to do with them. That they should stay away so I use: "мали грађанин". Could be translated as: "small towner". What about in Russian? I am looking for a word that is closer to the "мали građanin" on the scale, that is not derogatory, broad, that is not a swear word but could sting a little so they get the picture quickly no matter how slow they are. If the title is too broad please amend it. Response on this is not urgent.

Comment: what does "are only envy" mean?

Comment: how can people be "jealousy"? Do you mean "are envious or jealous"?

Comment: "white trash" are not necessarily envious or jealous of others, it's not something that defines that group of people. Could you please maybe think of another example to describe what you are after?

Comment: this does not make it any more clear. Please provide some context, a portion of text with a placeholder to fill.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I think I got two good answers on this topic. I have to run to catch a lecture but I will award one of them when I get back or when in transit.

Comment: @торстен, the two answers you've got are about very different things, it seems that people didn't understand your question properly (at least one of them). I can't understand it either. Could you provide some examples of complete sentences (in English), where you want to use this word?

Comment: can you please clarify the "мали грађанин" part - which language are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `провинциал`? It's not derogatory but definitely stingy.

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/провинциал](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB)

Comment: провинциал is good enough to what I am looking for. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I would use недалёкий (from недалеко - not far (reaching), implies that the person doesn't know much)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, it's [обыватель](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C).

*неодобр.* человек, лишенный общественного кругозора, живущий только мелкими личными интересами

Answer (score 1):

As one of the answers proposed: *`провинциал`* is a good choice but there are few more well-known in speech alternatives, like *`село`*, *`сельпо`*, or more politely: *`невежа`*

Answer (score 0):

"Белое пальто" - from meme "Вы все дураки и не лечитесь одна я умная в белом пальто стою красивая".

"Он в белом пальто"/"белопальтовый" - describes the one who thinks he's smart and cool. But envious and not so cool, as he thinks about himself. Note: this term is not really widespead, only internet users would understand it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, since "провинциал" is suggested for another answer. Probably, the word TS looks for is "гопник" = "redneck". This one is widespread.

Comment: ОК, new corrections in the question text. Here is the answer for new edition: "невежа" ("ignoramus"). This word is kind of bookish though. Maybe, "дерёвня" (this one is colloquial) or "колхозник". All of above describes low level of knowledge.
The most simple term, which is also invective, but not obscene, is "лох".

Comment: `Maybe, "дерёвня"` IMO, "Деревня" is the best option which still belongs to modern speech. That mentioned above "провинциал" or "колхозник" seem quite outdated to me.

Comment: "Деревня" without intended mistake "ё" seems outdated to me.

Comment: Please don't improve your answer in comments - some people do not read them. I was surprised to see much better answer in comment. People vote for answers, not for comments. You can always edit your own posts.